# Creating Dynamic types to IQueryable<T> at runtime in #

Tags: c#, multilingual, iqueryable

I'm developing a multilingual news portal website using asp.net and c#. Currently the site supports two languages and it will be extended to other additional languages when required. So it is my job to create the basic framework for the site. Based on the client requirements,the content to be stored in the database for the website for the different languages may be different. So, I have created different tables to store the News in different languages (like tblNews_EN, tblNews_am, etc) to store content for Enlish or Amharic languages.

Now I have classes to retrieve the latest news but I want to generalize those classes and retrieve the latest news for the specific culture being requested by the user. Initially I have something like the following which only work to retrieve latest news from the tblNews_EN table.

```
public IQueryable<GetNews> GetTopExtraNews()
 {

        var topExtraNews = from p in db.GetNews
                           where p.TopOrderPriority == 2
                           orderby p.NewsDate descending
                           select p;
        return topExtraNews;
}
```

Here GetNews is my Entity class that corresponds to the tblNews_EN table.

Now I want to generalize this one so that it will return objects from different tables depending on the culture selected. I tried to use something like IQueryable but I dont think this is the best option to deal with my case. So, is there any better option to do this?

Comment: Why are you not using a tool that already does this, like Orchard CMS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well all of your tables have the same structure.

Based on that just send the table as a parameter to your method and use this parameter to your query:

```
public IQueryable<GetNews> GetTopExtraNews(typeofYourTable myTable)
{

        var topExtraNews = from p in myTable
                           where p.TopOrderPriority == 2
                           orderby p.NewsDate descending
                           select p;
        return topExtraNews;
}
```

Of course you have to set the myTable parameter to the correct language table before calling your method.

Comment: Yes the tables has similar structure. But am not sure how to use the typeofYourTable type. Can you give me some more example how to use that?

Comment: @semytech I meant to place there the real Type of your class that refers to your table for example DataTable. Your db.GetNews is of some kind of Type. This type you have to put there to define what kind of parameter the method will accept.

Comment: I understand now but the <GetNews> in the IQueryable and db.GetNews are specific to one table. I want to generalize them so that whenver I call this function, I have to pass different types such as db.GetNews_EN, etc. Let me give you the code which I am currently trying but still not sure how to pass different types at runtime.